# Exporting a LaTeX table from R with the derivmkts package

Tags: tables, r, export

I'm fairly new to R and I'm currently playing around with the R derivmkts package and it's binomopt function. The function gives me an output of the option prices and stock prices that are visible as a table in the console. How can I export these tables to latex tables?
Code below

```
S=110 K=100, v=0.2, tt=2, d=0, n=12

binomopt(S, K, v, r, tt, d, n, american = FALSE,
         putopt=FALSE, specifyupdn=FALSE, crr=TRUE, jarrowrudd=FALSE,
         up=1.5, dn=0.5, returntrees=TRUE, returnparams=TRUE,
         returngreeks=FALSE)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

<<results='asis',echo=F>>=
library(derivmkts)

    S=110
    K=100
    v=0.2
    tt=2
    d=0
    n=12

    x <- binomopt(S, K, v, tt, d, n, american = FALSE,
             putopt=FALSE, specifyupdn=FALSE, crr=TRUE, jarrowrudd=FALSE,
             up=1.5, dn=0.5, returntrees=TRUE, returnparams=TRUE,
             returngreeks=FALSE)

    knitr::kable(x, "latex", booktabs=TRUE)

    # For single tables:
    # 
    # knitr::kable(x$stree, "latex", booktabs=TRUE)
    # knitr::kable(x$params, "latex", booktabs=TRUE)
    # # etc ...

@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fran. That was really helpful.